# Multi-level process development

Tags: process, terminology, process-engineering

I was previously acquainted with a specific model, which contains levels for different phases of a systems development, ie:

Phase 1: Complete chaos, nothing works
Phase 2: Getting stuff to work, but breaks, no process
Phase 3: Implement processes to stop things breaking
Phase 4: Scale 
etc..

I think it had an acronym like MMCM or MMCP or such, but can't find it via Googling.

Comment: Are you referring to CMMI?

Comment: yes, please convert this to an answer and points goeth to you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be looking for [Capability Maturity Model Integration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capability_Maturity_Model_Integration) (CMMI). The [CMMI Institute](http://cmmiinstitute.com/) seems to be the organization currently behind it.